# How to add member to Google Group

Tags: python, google-groups, google-groups-api, google-admin-settings-api

I have an appengine project where I am attempting to add a user to a Google group.

I am using a `GroupsProvisioningClient` in order to do so.
When I add a certain user to the group the code appears to work (no error is reported) but the user doesn't show up in the groups front end, not if I loop through `RetrieveAllMembers`.

When I attempt to `RetrieveGroupMember('group_email', 'user_email')` I get an error:

```
<error errorCode="1301" invalidInput="user@gmail.com" reason="EntityDoesNotExist" />
```

But when I attempt to manually add this user in the groups front end I also get an error:

```
user@gmail.com is already in this group
```

So I'm not sure what's going in, is or isn't my user in the group? How can I check? Is my code wrong?

```
client = gdata.apps.groups.client.GroupsProvisioningClient(domain=settings.DOMAIN)
client.ssl = True
client.auth_token = gdata.gauth.OAuthHmacToken(settings.OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, settings.OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, access_token.token, access_token.token_secret, gdata.gauth.ACCESS_TOKEN)
client.AddMemberToGroup('group_email', 'user_email')
client.RetrieveGroupMember('group_email', 'user_email')
```

Comment: For `user@gmail.com` in your case, what happens if you were to run just the `client.RetrieveGroupMember` method now (i.e. a period of time after it was created)? It could be that it needs more time to propagate than is being given in your code. Also, I believe `AddMemberToGroup` returns an entry representing that user, so if you needed to execute additional code on that user you could do so on the returned object.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've just retried running RetrieveGroupMember on its own and I still recieve the same error.RequestError: Server responded with: 400, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AppsForYourDomainErrors>
  <error errorCode="1301" invalidInput="user@gmail.com" reason="EntityDoesNotExist" />
</AppsForYourDomainErrors>

Comment: Okay, did some more thinking - I do not have any direct experience with the Provisioning API, but is it possible that you need to create the member before adding them? My very limited (as of today :) ) understanding is that a domain admin handles the creation of users/assignation to groups, etc., so in order for that to work you would have to create a user account specific to your domain. Again, this is a shot in the dark, but hopefully we can sort this out one way or another!

Comment: Thanks for spending your time on this :) ... The person I am trying to add is an existing gmail user (@gmail.com), the group created within the cPannel of a Google Apps domain. As far as I know there is no reason I can't add a user from a different domain to my group. In fact I have done it with other users already, it is just this one user that I am having an issue with.

Comment: And is there anything particular about the name? Non-ASCII characters, for instance? If you can add other Gmail users perhaps it is a random character in the name somewhere that causes the HTTP request to submit improperly?

Comment: Just to close this off for anyone reading this at a later date, I've stoped investigating the issue as it is not a priority for my client anymore. It was not a character encoding issue, the user in question had no acented characters in their name. I never did figure out the cause.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help. Good luck with everything!